# TelemetryClient request tracking end to end with trace

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

It is possible to trace a request along with any traces that I have added via the `TelemetryClient`. In a nutshell, I am using:

```
var id = "a very unique id";
using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Name", id, id))
{
telemetryClient.Trace("I have done something", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "uniqueId", id } );
telemetryClient.Trace("I am doing something else", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "uniqueId", id } );
}
```

The problem here is that the `operationId` isn't set nor the `operationParentId`.

Perhaps I am using this incorrectly but I was hoping to do a `join` between `traces` and `requests` on `operationParentId` so I can get the full picture.

Comment: Do you solve your issue as per the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the latest version of [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.10.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/)

With the latest nuget package installed, I test the code you provide, operationId / operationParentId are set properly.

Code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = "xxxx" };

            string id = "b123456";
            using (client.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("op_name",id,id))
            {
                client.TrackTrace("I have done something", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "my_uniqueId", id } } );
                client.TrackTrace("I am doing something else", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "my_uniqueId", id } } );    
            }    

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

In portal:

**Request telemetry:**

[image]

**Trace telemetry:**

[image]

Comment: Not OP, but it turns out that even as of 2.14.0, how you initialize your client and instrumentation key can affect the behavior of the API.  So if you use this:  `TelemetryConfiguration` to initialize the key, you will NOT get any correlation.  You must directly set the `TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey`.  See this post for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717627/116051